# CMake find_package_handle_standard_args not silently failing when wrong version is found?

Tags: cmake

I'm writing a custom `FindXXX.cmake` for an imported target, at some point I call

```
find_package_handle_standard_args(XXX
    REQUIRED_VARS XXX_ROOT_DIR
    VERSION_VAR XXX_VERSION)
```

Now, it may happen that I found the imported target (`XXX_ROOT_DIR` is defined), but that the version is incorrect. In this case, I'd expect something like this:

```
find_package(XXX 4.5)  # no REQUIRED
```

...to not fail and simply set `XXX_Found` to `false`. Currently, this throw a hard-error.

Can I achieve this with `find_package_handle_standard_args`? I could unset `XXX_ROOT_DIR` if the version is not correct but then I'd not to perform whatever is done in `find_package_handle_standard_args` twice.

---

The actual error is

```
CMake Error at I:/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:160 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    I:/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:160

  when parsing string

    Could NOT find XXX: Found unsuitable version "4.7", but required is exact version "3.8" (found I:\Softwares\XXX)

  Invalid character escape '\S'.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  I:/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:456 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  I:/.../FindXXX.cmake:106 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

Comment: It could be useful to show that "hard-error". Especially if you suspect (according to the answer) that something wrong with parameters you have passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the actual error message but as I said, it's because `XXX_ROOT_DIR` contains \ on Windows which break the message builder of `FindPackageHandleStandardArgs`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what do you mean by "hard error", but the error message is **clearly** about the path `"I:\Softwares\XXX`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev By "hard error" I mean a fatal error, not a simple warning as it should have been since the `REQUIRED` flag was not present. I know that the message is clearly about the path, I just did not expect `find_package_handle_standard_args` to fail on this since the path is used everything in my `FindXXX.cmake` without any issue, and since I'm pretty new to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (and did not read correctly the message), I thought that this was the expected behavior (i.e. fail even if `REQUIRED` is missing when a wrong version is found), hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here since someone might found this while facing a similar issue...

The problem is not at all `find_package_handle_standard_args` but a bug (I guess we can call it that) in CMake that breaks `find_package_handle_standard_args` when one of the variable contains `\`, typically Windows path.

Converting the `\` into CMake `/` using

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${XXX_ROOT_DIR}" XXX_ROOT_DIR)
```

...solves the issue.